Cross post from other places
I posted my question at two other places (cross validated and economics). I haven't got an answer at either place - cross validated for over 2 weeks and economics for 1 week. Can I cross post the question in quantitative finance? It's about a certain econometrics model used by Fed. 

Please see here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/266114
